# Deleted EFI partition Windows 8

Tags: windows, boot, efi

I dual boot windows 7 and 8 and I accidently converted my windows 8 disk to dynamic while I was in 7.

I used AOMEI Dynamic Disk Manager to turn it back to basic, but it removed my EFI partition. Now windows 8 won't boot.

Is there any way I can install the non-EFI bootloader on the windows 8 partition and use legacy mode?

Or recover the EFI partition?

Or create an EFI File on a usb - anything so I can boot back into my windows 8!!

Using the windows recovery CD or reinstalling isn't an option.

I need help fast to get the windows 8 booting again!

Comment: Can you switch to a non-EFI installation at this point, no, you cannot.

Comment: As I understand [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) can help you.  
And maybe this is possible duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/480730/lost-windows-7-boot-after-easybcd-with-efi?rq=1)?

Answer (score -2):

Easy fix.

Firstly, change the disk to MBR rather than GPT, make sure Windows 8 partition is primary.

Get [a copy of bootsect.exe and bcdboot.exe from Windows Automated Installation Kit](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/156869-get-waik-tools-wo-downloading-the-huge-isos/)

Run `bootsect /nt60 E: /s E:` (change E: to Windows 8 Partition)

Run `bcdboot E: /s E:` (change E: to Windows 8 Partition)

What this does is changes the disk to MBR to allow BIOS booting, installs the bootloader and created a BCD store on the Windows 8 partition, allowing it to boot without the plague called UEFI. You will need to ensure legacy boot mode is enabled on your computer.